# point of defining classes

Tags: class, dart, flutter

This may sound broad and ignorant, possibly because it is and I am.

Here goes:

On the page https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-the-power-of-small-and-reusable-widgets-7649e3b0bca2 I found this example code for setting up a class to define a color palette, like this: *(shortened for brevity)*

```
class Palette {
  static Color blueSky = Color(0xFF068FFA);
  static Color greenLand = Color(0xFF89ED91);
  static Color blueSkyLight = Color(0x40068FFA);
  static Color greenLandLight = Color(0x4089ED91);
  static Color blueSkyLighter = Color(0x10068FFA);
}
```

The class is then later used as follows:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
        Palette.blueSky,
        Palette.greenLand,
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```

Now somebody riddle me this: What is the point of defining the class? Why not simply define a bunch of variables, like so:

```
static Color _blueSky = Color(0xFF068FFA);
static Color _greenLand = Color(0xFF89ED91);
static Color _blueSkyLight = Color(0x40068FFA);
static Color _greenLandLight = Color(0x4089ED91);
static Color _blueSkyLighter = Color(0x10068FFA);
```

...and then later use like this:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      colors: [
        _blueSky,
        _greenLand,
      ],
    ),
  )
);
```

I mean, it's clearly shorter (even though I even used those ridiculous underscores to make the vars private, which is another thing I find pointless), and I don't see **any** upside in defining a class over simply defining some variables. Zero. Why make things unneccessarily complicated?

Is it really purely a question of "coding philosophy" (whatever that's supposed to mean exactly) or personal taste in "coding style"? Because that's what it all looks like to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's something even Flutter does with `Colors` class.

It:

- gives a context to variables. "blue" is not the same thing on Android and iOS for example. It may rightfully be different in your custom app.
- improves discoverability. With a class, we can type `Palette.` and the IDE will list all the possibilities.
- prevents confusing name shadowing. We can name a variable `blue` and we'll still be able to use `Palette.blue`
- works well with Dart imports (show/hide directives)

Example:

```
export 'colors.dart' show Palette;
```

That's much better than:

```
export 'colors.dart' show blue, red, green, purple, ...;
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I get the point now, but it guess it's just not for me. None of these points/upsides you list are relevant to me. I can see, though, why people find it helpful. I just find it "unneccessarily complicated", but I geuess that's just individual style. :) But again, thanks for clarifying.